# How do I change the order in a calendar overlay when two items share the same day?

Tags: 2010, calendar

I have setup a calendar overlay.

I have added two custom Calendars to the overlay.  I have tried different combinations of adding CalA and CalB
When the calendars share the same day CalB is always on the top and CalA is always on the bottom.

I would like to have CalA always on the top.

Some other notes than may be causing this:

- I have generalized names in case this is a naming problem.  The
  calendars names start with P and O.  The O calendar is always on top.
- CalB always has longer time periods.  Date ranges are always 7 days. 
  CalA are always under 5 days.

Answer (score 1):

If you have added Calender A as an overlay to Calender B, i.e in calender B settings, you have selected calender overlay and selected calender A, try other way around.

i.e Go to calender A settings, choose calender overlay and select calender B.

Its working at my end.

Comment: The base calendar is empty.  I have added the two custom calendars to the overlay.

Answer (score -1):

Sounds like an alphabetical ordering.  Rename your calendars with an index character first, ie.  1-CalA  & 2-CalB.